# Windows - code to block toast notifications? (Win32/MFC desktop)

Tags: winapi, toast

Everything I can find on toast notifications is about how to send them or fix problems with sending them.

I have a full-screen desktop application where I want to STOP toast from popping up while it runs.

So far the only way I've found to do this is manually -- group policy, user going to Windows settings.

The MS docs on toast notifications list a property to tell you if toast is blocked, but it is read-only so you can't set it with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable notifications (toasts) with the **NOC_GLOBAL_SETTING_TOASTS_ENABLED** value